# How to mark user database as system database in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2014

is it possible to force user defined database act as system database?

What i want to achieve?

I have 2 backup plans - one for `all system databases`, second for `all user databases`. Now, without any changes in my maintenance plans i want to move one of my databases from one maintenance plan to other.

Answer (score 1):

There is no database property that indicates a system database.  System databases are nothing more than a hard-coded list of database names (master, model, msdb, etc.) that may vary depending on the context.  For example, `tempdb` is a system database in SSMS Object Explorer but not considered a system database in maintenance plans.

Rather than maintenances plans, consider [Ola Hallengren's SQL Maintenance Solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/).  This is widely used in the SQL Server community, performing SQL database maintenance tasks using T-SQL and SQL Agent jobs.  It is also extensible according to your special needs.  For example, you could customize the backup script to use a table of user databases to be backed up in addition to system databases when `SYSTEM_DATABASES` is specified, and exclude those databases when `USER_DATABASES` is specified. That would allow you to add or remove databases without changing the plans going forward.